# How to say "to speak over someone"?

Tags: word-choice

How would I express to my colleague that someone was talking over someone else in a meeting and not letting them speak?

Comment: The question would benefit from more specific context, especially, since *speak over* does not seem to be an established phrase in English: not letting speak by speaking all the time oneself?

Comment: @guidot: I don't know about "well established", but it is a phrase with a specific meaning. see [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/107100). I'm not sure that it would translate into German though; it's certainly considered a bit rude in the U.S., so perhaps it's not even considered possible in Germany.

Comment: @guidot: PS. It's probably more common to say "talk over", see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talk_over) definition 3. Imo it's not quite the same as "interrupt", which implies that the other person stops talking, "talk over" means to start talking while the other person is talking, and continue whether or not the other person stops.

Answer (score 5):

> jemandem über den Mund fahren (colloquial, casual)

rudely interrupt

> jemanden unterbrechen

interrupt / cut someone off

---

> jemanden nicht ausreden lassen

not letting someone finish

---

> jemanden nicht zu Wort kommen lassen

not letting someone have a say

---

**example:**

> Er hat ihn andauernd unterbrochen und nie zu Wort kommen lassen.

> He constantly interrupted him and never let him get a word in edgewise.

Comment: _Ins Wort fallen_ might also be a good candidate.

Comment: Other suggestions: jemandem das Wort abschneiden; andere übertonen. In my opinion the best variant is "jemanden nicht zu Wort kommen lassen". The other phrases suggest that another speaker is interrupted.

Comment: @PaulFrost *übertonen* ist kein deutsches Wort *übertönen* schon.

Comment: Neben *übertönen* (das sich eigentlich eher auf Singen bezieht, aber auch auf sonst sehr lautes Umfeld und dann im positiven Sinne meint, sich trotzdem Gehör verschaffen zu können) können Wörter wie *überschreien* oder *überbrüllen* in Fällen eingesetzt werden, wo es wirklich sehr laut zugeht und der Lauteste „gewinnt“, in diesen Fällen schwingt eher eine negative Wertung mit.

Comment: @Wolf Certainly not, it was a typo.